# Join two documents in mongoDB even if there is no entry in the right joined collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Please help me out by letting me know how to write the syntax for joining two collections in MongoDB. I want all the entries of the left joined collection. If there is no matching entry in the right collection then it should be populated as a blank field.

see below code,

```
public class Instance
{
    public long IId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long TemplateId { get; set; }
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public long TId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public List<Sample> Samples { get; set; }
}

public class Sample
{
    public long SId { get; set; }
    public long TemplateId { get; set; }
    public long SampleData { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

I use below code for join collactions,

```
var data = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Instance>("Instance").Aggregate()
    .Lookup("Templates", "TemplateId", "TId", @as: "Template")
    .Lookup("Sample", "TemplateId", "TemplateId", @as: "Template.Samples")
    .Unwind("Template")
    .Unwind("Template.Samples")
    .As<Instance>()        
    .ToList();
```

Here what happening, if there is a document in Instance collection and no relevant matching document is present in Template or Sample collection then Instance document is also not coming to the list.

I want all Instance documents even if there is no matching Template or Sample document available.

Comment: I think unwind Template stage should come before attempting to add a Template.Samples field

Comment: [preserveNullAndEmptyArrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#std-label-unwind-preserveNullAndEmptyArrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preserveNullAndEmptyArrays - boolean Optional.

If true, if the path is null, missing, or an empty array,
$unwind
outputs the document.

If false, if path is null, missing, or an empty array,
$unwind
does not output a document.

The default value is false.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#std-label-unwind-preserveNullAndEmptyArrays